# flutter http post request showing status code 500 although its works in postman

Tags: api, flutter, http-post, http-status-code-500

```
**flutter**
```

As you can see below code of post method in which i pass static data for post through post API,
those data are work in postman but not in this method

```
    Future addbuss() async {
    var urlpost = "https://jcien.com/api/addBusinessReceived";
    var responce = await http.post(urlpost,
    
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      
    },
        body: jsonEncode({
          "user": "7",
          "ch_id": "1",
          "user_from": "9",
          "entry_date": "2021-05-31",
          "amount": "1234",
          "business_type": "new",
          "referral_type": "inside",
          "remarks": "demoapii",
        }));
    print(responce.statusCode);
**statusCode**
status code showing error of 500   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self-explanatory:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must debug your API, the error is from there.
Check log server.

Answer (score 0):

I think It might be because of

```
 headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
         },
```

Use this instead

```
 headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       },
```